# Can Exchange be forced to keep all mail?

Tags: permissions, exchange-2003, pop3

I have an Exchange 2003 box that is read by an old POP3 application that has no configurable options apart from server/username/password, and it's deleting the old messages from the mailbox after it has finished.

Is it possible to force Exchange to not delete the messages? I'm guessing there's some permissions I can set somewhere but I *hate* Exchange 2003 and I've no idea where to even start looking.

I've got every intention of moving it to Exchange 2007/2010 in the future, so if anyone knows any solutions for 2007/2010 I would be glad to hear them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Exchange 2003 you can set up message archiving on the mailbox store level (which would archive all messages sent or received on that mailbox store) or you could create an "archive" mailbox and set up the POP applications' mailbox to forward a copy of all received messages to this "archive" mailbox.

Comment: Double +1 because this also has no chance of pissing off the legacy app when it's unable to delete messages.

Comment: This is good, thanks! It also indirectly solves another issue I was trying to figure out how to solve.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 1):

No solution needed for 2010 - this is part of the out of the box behavior. Archiving, Retention policies. Check whether it matches your needs:

http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/en/us/archiving-and-retention.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Exchange 2007 supports single user journaling.  Below are some links regarding this functionality.

[Overview of Exchange 2007 Journaling](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.12.journaling.aspx)

[Configuration examples](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Exchange-Server-2007-Using-Journaling-Rules.html)